# how to merge two ext4 partition?

Tags: partitioning, merge

I have 9 partitions of which one is unallocated and i want to merge this unallocated partion to sdb11 partition on which my ubuntu is installed?[image: partition image link]

Comment: There is no such thing as "unalolcated partition". You have 8 partitions.

Comment: Make sure you have good backups of everything what ever you do. But moving all those partitions has more risk. Better to use as a /home or /data partition. If /home. To move /home uses rsync- Be sure to use parameters to preserve ownership & permissions 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving Shows on second drive, but can be same drive: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting

Comment: @K7AAY if you delete sdb10, and recreate it later, remember that you'll have to edit /etc/fstab :-)

Comment: Of course, if you just want to use that additional space, you don't have to move anything.  Make a partition, put an ext4 filesystem on it, and mount it in some place you want, like /var/local/data or /home/<user>/mydata, etc. Use symlinks to the new mount point, like Documents2 from your home.

Comment: The simplest way requires them adjacent, but there are partitions between. sdb11 is locked, which means you booted from this drive, and you can't change partitions on a drive you booted from. so you must boot from a LiveUSB or other drive to make changes you want. After reboot, you'd need to move sdb7 to the front of the drive & accept the change; move sdb8 to the front of the drive & accept the change; move sdb9 to the front of the drive & accept the change; delete sdb10 after swapoff before doing anything to sdb11, then, either make a new swap partition or swap file; ubfan1's idea is better.

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Status please...

Comment: Status please...

Answer (score 0):

## Make sure that you have a good backup of your important files, as this procedure can corrupt or lose data.

**The NTFS part...**

I'm not a Windows guy per se, so I don't know if the Windows Disk Management app can move disk partitions, but if it can, use it to move /dev/sdb7 and /dev/sdb8 partitions all the way left.

---

**The Ubuntu part...**

Keep these things in mind:

- always start the entire procedure with issuing a `swapoff` on any mounted swap partitions, and end the entire procedure with issuing a `swapon` on that same swap partition
- a **move** is done by pointing the mouse pointer at the center of a partition and dragging it left/right with the hand cursor
- a **resize** is done by dragging the left/right side of a partition to the left/right with the directional arrow cursor
- if any partition can't be **moved/resized** graphically, you may have to manually enter the specific required numeric data (don't do this unless I instruct you to)
- you begin any **move/resize** by right-clicking on the partition in the lower pane of the main window, and selecting the desired action from the popup menu, then finishing that action in the new **move/resize** window

**Note**: I'll write this portion as if you couldn't move /dev/sdb7 and /dev/sdb8 using Windows Disk Management app.

**Note**: if the procedure doesn't work exactly as I outline, **STOP** immediately and **DO NOT** continue.

- boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB
- start `gparted`
- **move** /dev/sdb7 partition all the way left
- **move** /dev/sdb8 partition all the way left
- **move** /dev/sdb9, /dev/sdb10, and /dev/sdb11 partitions all the way left
- **resize** the right side of /dev/sdb11 all the way right
- click the Apply icon
- quit `gparted`
- reboot

  - If you have any Ubuntu boot issues, contact me and I'll give you a fix

Comment: Moving Ubuntu `/` will require reinstall grub.

Comment: @Pilot6 Why? Inquiring minds want to know :-) The UUID stays the same. I've moved many Ubuntu / partitions and I've never had to reinstall GRUB. If required, what's the best command to do that? `sudo grub-install /dev/sdb`?

Comment: If you move the "left-hand side" of `/` partition, grub won't find it on boot. Something like that is needed. `chroot` to the system and at least `update-grub`.

Comment: Grub uses UUID, UUID will not be changed when moving a partition, so Grub should still work.

Comment: @Pilot6 Moving the /dev/sdb11 partition, and resizing the right side keeps the left side intact. That's why I do it in that order.

Comment: In this case I don't see a way without moving the left side of sda11. Either you add space there, or move the whole partition.

Comment: @Pilot6 I MOVE the whole partition, and RESIZE to the right.

Comment: When you move the whole partition. the left side of it moves too. grub looks for a specific sector on disk.

Comment: @Pilot6 I'm not aware that GRUB looks for sectors. Are you sure?

Comment: I shot this way into my foot a couple of times. ;-) I am quite sure.

Comment: @Pilot6 Does my `sudo grub-install /dev/sdb` command look correct without chroot?

Comment: It doesn't make sense from Live without chroot.

Comment: @Pilot6 I just did `cat /boot/grub/grub.cfg` and I didn't notice anything about sectors. Maybe I missed it. Can you find the specific line in your grub.cfg?

Comment: It is not in `grub.cfg`. This is all about where to look for `grub.cfg` ))

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/104272/discussion-between-heynnema-and-pilot6).

Comment: I believe it depends on whether grub is using blocklists or not. Block lists are hard coded. It may also depend if UEFI or BIOS boot.